# Given an optional mutable reference, can I pass it to another function without moving it?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am working on a little Rust project where many functions take an optional mutable reference to a `struct`. For simplicity, let's say that this `struct` is a `String`. So the functions look something like this:

```
fn append_to_string(maybe_string: Option<&mut String>) {
    if let Some(s) = maybe_string {
        s.push('1');
    }
}
```

My `main` function has ownership of the optional structure. So it can easily call these functions using `Option::as_mut`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut maybe_string = Some(String::new());
    append_to_string(maybe_string.as_mut());
    println!("{:?}", maybe_string);
}
```

This all seems to work fine. But the problem comes when one of the functions needs to call others.

```
fn append_multiple_to_string(maybe_string: Option<&mut String>) {
    for _ in 0..2 {
        append_to_string(maybe_string);
    }
}
```

I can't compile this, because `append_multiple_to_string` moves `maybe_string` into `append_to_string` in the first iteration of the loop, so it can't use it again in subsequent iterations of the loop. See [this Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20maybe_string%20%3D%20Some(String%3A%3Anew())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20append_multiple_to_string(maybe_string.as_mut())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20maybe_string)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20append_to_string(maybe_string%3A%20Option%3C%26mut%20String%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20let%20Some(s)%20%3D%20maybe_string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20s.push(%271%27)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20append_multiple_to_string(maybe_string%3A%20Option%3C%26mut%20String%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20_%20in%200..2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20append_to_string(maybe_string)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A).

I've actually figured out a way to make this work by extracting the reference from the `Option` and constructing a new `Option` for each iteration, like this ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20maybe_string%20%3D%20Some(String%3A%3Anew())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20append_multiple_to_string(maybe_string.as_mut())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20maybe_string)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20append_to_string(maybe_string%3A%20Option%3C%26mut%20String%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20let%20Some(s)%20%3D%20maybe_string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20s.push(%271%27)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20append_multiple_to_string(maybe_string%3A%20Option%3C%26mut%20String%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20match%20maybe_string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some(string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20_%20in%200..2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20append_to_string(Some(string))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20_%20in%200..2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20append_to_string(None)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)):

```
fn append_multiple_to_string(maybe_string: Option<&mut String>) {
    match maybe_string {
        Some(string) => {
            for _ in 0..2 {
                append_to_string(Some(string));
            }
        }
        None => {
            for _ in 0..2 {
                append_to_string(None);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this feels very cumbersome and I don't love that I have to repeat basically the same code twice to make it work. I feel like I must be missing a more elegant way of doing this, but I just don't seem to be able to figure out what it is. I guess I could make a macro that could take one copy of the code and expand it, but I have written macros before and I find them to be difficult to write and maintain, so I'd rather avoid that.

I assume that there is no way to make a copy of the `Option` to pass in, because then I would have two simultaneous mutable references to the same data. So am I just stuck with the ugly code that I have?

I'm open to changing the argument type away from `Option<&mut String>`, but I'm not sure what to change it to so that I can avoid this problem. If I do need to change it, I would prefer not to change it in such a way that the functions can change the value of `main`'s `maybe_string.is_some()`. That is to say, with my current code, if a function calls `maybe_string.take()`, it is only taking the value out of its copy of the `Option`, not `main`'s copy.

I would also prefer not to solve this problem using `unsafe` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Option::as_deref_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref_mut):

```rust
fn append_multiple_to_string(mut maybe_string: Option<&mut String>) {
//                           ^^^
    for _ in 0..2 {
        append_to_string(maybe_string.as_deref_mut());
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

`as_deref_mut` will turn a `&'a mut Option<P>` (where `P` is a mutable pointer type implementing [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html)) into an `Option<&'a mut P::Target>`. In the case of a `&mut T` pointer, this means it will just turn a `&'a mut Option<&'b mut T>` into an `Option<&'a mut T>`, but it also works with other mutable pointer types, such as `&'a mut Option<Box<T>>` → `Option<&'a mut T>` or `&'a mut Option<String>` → `Option<&'a mut str>`.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks! But I don't understand why this method doesn't violate borrow checker rules. It seems like it returns a mutable reference to the underlying data while the original `Option` continues to have a mutable reference to the same data. I thought that the borrow checker didn't allow such a thing.

Comment: @bytesized It works because it doesn't copy the `Option<&mut T>`, but it _reborrows_ it with a shorter lifetime. There's no problem with the borrow checker because there's only a single "active" mutable reference, since `maybe_string` becomes "inactive" (and can't be used) while it itself is mutably borrowed, until `append_to_string` returns and releases its borrow.